# Why won't pygame display my text?

Tags: python, text, pygame

My code looks like this, and it opens up the display alright and makes the background white, but it refuses to show my text. It dosnt give any errors either.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
black = (0, 0, 0)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1250,700))
white = (255, 255, 255)
def text_objects(text, font, color):
        textSurface = font.render(text, True, color,)
        return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def letter_input():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    smallText = pygame.font.Font("txt.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects ("Please input something to say", smallText, black)
    textRect.center = (11250/2), (700/2)
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()




letter_input()


pygame.display.set_caption("Sentence printer")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Quite frankly, I'm just confused at why it won't do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
textRect.center = (11250/2), (700/2)
```

Here you set the topleft coordinates of the rect to (5625.0, 350.0) and that's outside of your `gameDisplay`. Try for example `textRect.center = (500, 300)` instead.